# Phaser 3 set StaticGroup opacity

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to set the opacity of the platforms for the phaser project i'm working on.

I tried using

```
 platforms.alpha = 0.2;
```

Could anyone recommend a way to do this? It seems to work with sprites but not the platforms.

I am using Phaser 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

it's .setAlpha(alpha) on whatever object you want.

For more info (much better than the phaser documentation imo): https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/gameobject/#alpha